# Is there any benefit to having a WiFi adapter if I have a router/modem?

Tags: adapter

Is there any benefit to having a WiFi adapter if I have a router/modem? Would it strengthen my son's PS4 online connection?

Answer (score 1):

If your son's PS4 is conencted with an Ethernet cable to the router/modem, then that is as good as it gets.

Wireless has less bandwidth and more latency.  Its advantage is the lack of physical wires.

Comment: So if I have a wireless router, no ethernet cables used.... there really is no need for a wifi adapter, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, the PS4 has wifi built in.  no need for anything else.